# Error while creating query_string in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have written an flask app.

This app allow users to upload images, if i run this app locally this app uploads images and saves it to the path which i have designated

Now i want to create a query string for my app where i will create urls and send it to people to upload images.

but when i run my app i receive this error

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index'. Did you forget to specify values ['property_id']?
Traceback (most recent call last)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__

    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app

    response = self.handle_exception(e)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise

    raise value

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise

    raise value

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request

    rv = self.dispatch_request()

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request

    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\Desktop\python-projects\new\app.py", line 77, in index

    return render_template('index.html', property_id= property_id)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 135, in render_template

    context, ctx.app)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 117, in _render

    rv = template.render(context)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render

    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1008, in render

    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 37, in reraise

    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\Desktop\python-projects\new\templates\index.html", line 14, in top-level template code

    {{ dropzone.create(action_view='index') }}

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask_dropzone\__init__.py", line 330, in create

    action_url = url_for(action_view, **kwargs)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 356, in url_for

    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2061, in handle_url_build_error

    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise

    raise value

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 345, in url_for

    force_external=external)

    File "C:\Users\prince.bhatia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 1776, in build

    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)

    werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index'. Did you forget to specify values ['property_id']?

The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.

To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

    dump() shows all variables in the frame
    dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

Below is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for, send_file
from flask_dropzone import Dropzone
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES, patch_request_class
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
import psycopg2
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
dropzone = Dropzone(app)
#app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]="postgres://qpnwgdxnihlitm:22e4f6cbdb773f69aa468b2b7ddcd692552cb4102367ffc14c62f19403636477@ec2-54-243-223-245.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d1ssufnnr78nll?sslmode=require"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]= "postgresql://postgres:prince@25@localhost/images"
#app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]='postgres://mapvmydehdyncf:7500963c956e3d5556df4a5f4fdd1a9a40f023c922bfe93194fb13b9322c86ad@ec2-23-21-165-188.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d6lmau9918afdq?sslmode=require'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'supersecretkeygoeshere' 

# Dropzone settings
app.config['DROPZONE_UPLOAD_MULTIPLE'] = True
app.config['DROPZONE_ALLOWED_FILE_CUSTOM'] = True
app.config['DROPZONE_ALLOWED_FILE_TYPE'] = 'image/*'
app.config['DROPZONE_REDIRECT_VIEW'] = 'results'

# Uploads settings
app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = '/uploads'

photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, photos)
patch_request_class(app)  # set maximum file size, default is 16MB


class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "image"
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    link = db.Column(db.String(1000000), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = link

@app.route("/<string:property_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(property_id):

    # set session for image results
    if "file_urls" not in session:
        session['file_urls'] = []
    # list to hold our uploaded image urls
    file_urls = session['file_urls']

    # handle image upload from Dropszone
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_obj = request.files
        for f in file_obj:
            file = request.files.get(f)

            # save the file with to our photos folder
            filename = photos.save(
                file,
                name=file.filename    
            )

            # append image urls

            file_urls.append(photos.url(filename))
            d = file_urls.append(photos.url(filename))

            for i in file_urls:
                data = Data(i)
                db.session.add(data)
                db.session.commit()


        session['file_urls'] = file_urls

        return "uploading..."
    # return dropzone template on GET request

    return render_template('index.html', property_id= property_id)


@app.route('/results')
def results():

    # redirect to home if no images to display
    if "file_urls" not in session or session['file_urls'] == []:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    # set the file_urls and remove the session variable
    file_urls = session['file_urls']
    session.pop('file_urls', None)
    dms = set(file_urls)
    get_length = len(dms)

    return render_template('results.html', dms=dms, get_length=get_length)

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='images' user='postgres' password='prince@25' host='localhost' port='5432' ")
    print(conn)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    data = cur.execute("SELECT DISTINCT link FROM image")
    m_dict = cur.fetchall()

    filename = "Productivity.csv"
    with open("./"+filename,'w', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, m_dict)
        csvfile.writerow(["Link"])
        for i in range(0, len( m_dict )):
            csvfile.writerow( m_dict[i]  )

    news = cur.execute("DELETE FROM image")
    conn.commit()
    return send_file(filename, attachment_filename="Data.csv", as_attachment=True)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

#app.run(debug=True)
```

this my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>99Acres</title>
        {{ dropzone.load() }}
        {{ dropzone.style('border: 2px dashed #0087F7; margin: 10%; min-height: 400px;') }}
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:teal">
        <!--<h1 style="color:white;">99Acres</h1>-->
        <img align="right"src="https://img-d02.moneycontrol.co.in/news_image_files/2015/356x200/9/99acres_1902_356.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="me">
        <h1 align="center" style="color:white">Welcome to 99acres image upload website</h1>
        <h3 align="center"style="color:white">Please Upload images in format[".JPG",".PNG",".JPEG"]</h3>
        <h3 align="center" style="color:white">**Please Note:Maximum Total image size is 5MB</h3> 
        {{ dropzone.create(action_view='index') }}
        <div class="list" align="center">
            <strong>Our Partners:</strong> <a href="http://www.naukri.com" class="">Naukri.com</a>-
            <a href="http://www.jeevansathi.com" class="" style="color:white">Jeevansathi Matrimonials</a>- <a href="http://www.icicicommunities.org" class="">ICICIcommunities.org </a><br>
            <br>
            <a href="../propadmin/" class=""style="color:white">Home </a>|| <a href="../property/about.php" class=""style="color:white">About Us </a>||
            <a href="/do/buyourservices/" class=""> Advertise with us </a>|| <a href="../property/terms.php" class=""style="color:white">Terms and Conditions</a> ||
            <a href="../property/contact.php" class=""style="color:white"> Contact us</a> ||<a href="../property/request_info.php" class=""style="color:white"> Reques1t info</a><br>
            <br>
            All rights reserved 2001 Info Edge India Ltd. 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my results.html

```
<body style="background-color:teal">
<h1 align="center" style="color:white">Below Images Uploaded Successfully</h1>
<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Back</a><p>

<ul>
{% for file_url in dms %}
    <img style="height: 150px" src="{{ file_url }}">
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<h1 align="center" style="color:white">You can close this page or upload more image</h1>
<h1 align="center" style="color:white">Total number of images are : {{get_length}}</h1> <br><br><br><br>
<div class="list" align="center">
            <strong>Our Partners:</strong> <a href="http://www.naukri.com" class="">Naukri.com</a>-
            <a href="http://www.jeevansathi.com" class="" style="color:white">Jeevansathi Matrimonials</a>- <a href="http://www.icicicommunities.org" class="">ICICIcommunities.org </a><br>
            <br>
            <a href="../propadmin/" class=""style="color:white">Home </a>|| <a href="../property/about.php" class=""style="color:white">About Us </a>||
            <a href="/do/buyourservices/" class=""> Advertise with us </a>|| <a href="../property/terms.php" class=""style="color:white">Terms and Conditions</a> ||
            <a href="../property/contact.php" class=""style="color:white"> Contact us</a> ||<a href="../property/request_info.php" class=""style="color:white"> Reques1t info</a><br>
            <br>
            All rights reserved 2001 Info Edge India Ltd. 
        </div>
</body>
```

I have read this posts:

[werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'success'. Did you forget to specify values ['name']?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417742/werkzeug-routing-builderror-could-not-build-url-for-endpoint-success-did-you)

[How do you get a query string on Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774265/how-do-you-get-a-query-string-on-flask)

[werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234212/werkzeug-routing-builderror-could-not-build-url-for-endpoint)[image]

Answer (score 0):

> render_template('index.html', property_id= property_id)

Your `index.html` does not use `property_id`. You can discard the `property_id` argument if `index.html` indeed do not need it

**in index.html, line 14**

> dropzone.create(action_view='index')
>
> action_url = url_for(action_view, **kwargs)

the later `url_for` would invoke `index()` method again, but missed the argument `property_id`, and moreover it seemed that you are making a recursive call!

Comment: I cannot discard it ,i need to create urls with the property id and need to store ,but cant proceed because of error

Comment: I updated the answer, and the first comment is not the real cause.

Comment: i am attaching an image and this is received, it is not giving me the complete index.html just this page, 

what i want is when someone open http://127.0.0.1:5000/45, 

i should be able to capture the value of <property_id> and save it into database

Comment: However, the `dropzone.create(action_view='index')  -> url_for('index)` in `index.html` requires a `property_id` parameter, but you missed it

Comment: wait  let me explain you, if someone opens 127.0.0.1:5000/<property_id>, that person should see <property_id> and upload images and i am able to capture the that property_id to save it into database. But your updated way i am able to see property_id but half of html is not visible

Comment: check the image i have updated...now someone cannot upload images